# Running Sum of Filtered Rows in Tableau

Tags: filter, tableau-api, calculated-field, rolling-computation, level-of-detail

I have a table of challenge submissions (that records the time of submission of a challenge in a competition by different players, and whether the submission was correct or not) -

[image]

[image]

and another table that has the points associated with each challenge -

[image]

How do I plot a graph of running sum of points earned by the top 3 players in the competition over time (for last 24 hours only)? The catch here is that I only need to consider the first successful submission in case there are more than one successful submissions for a challenge in the competition (eg. Challenge #17 for Player A).

**EDIT:**

[Dummy Data](https://filebin.net/6w8fgsp1411icrza)

**Desired Output:**

[image]

Comment: Can you please upload a csv sample here as a code? It looks like that it can be done

Comment: @AnilGoyal added dummy data and desired output to the question

Comment: I have proposed an answer/walkthrough, please see if it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am proposing a solution/answer assuming a few things-

- Challenge acceptance time ends at 17:00 everyday
- Different lines represent different challenges

**Step-1** Create a CF to adjust date/time by calendar date - `adjusted date` as

```
DATEADD('hour', 7, [Date])
```

**Note that I have added 7 hours to make the last calendar date/time for submission as 00 AM next day.**

**Step-2** Create another CF `win_loss` as

```
If [Success]='W' then 1 ELSE 0 end
```

**step-3** create another CF `game points` as

```
[win_loss]*[Points (Points)]
```

**Step-4** create another CF `first win or loss` as (don't worry about loss here)

```
{FIXED [Player], [Challenge], [success] : MIN([Date])} = [Date]
```

**Step-5** create a set on 'players' field with TOP-3 with this formula (select top 3) by

```
sum(
IF [first win or loss]= TRUE
then [game points] END)
```

**Step-6** build your view by dragging

- `set`, `MDY(adjusted date)` & `first win or loss` on filters shelf/card
- add `mdy` filter to context
- `[date]` with `exact date` and `discreet` to columns
- `sum(game points)` to rows
- adding table calculation on measure - running total
- right click sum(game points) click `edit in shelf` and replace the existing calculation by this one-

```
RUNNING_SUM(ZN(SUM([game points])))
```

*(Note this will ensure your lines start at `f(x)=0` always)*

- `challenge` on colors in marks card
- `sum(game points)` to text in marks card.

*Note- filters on (i) `Set` will ensure the top 3 players are in view only
(ii) `adjusted date` will ensure view for 24 hour challenge submission time
(iii) `first win or loss` will eliminate second and subsequent win(s) by same player for same challenge*

I hope this will also make things clear to you.

You should get your desired view

[image]

OR change the date field to seconds to get a view like this

[image]

Comment: Hi @AnilGoyal, with regards to Step 5, if I sort by Sum(Game Points), wouldn't that also count the duplicate win points?

Comment: Also, is there a way to start the lines at Y-Axis (X=0) if we are only showing the last 24 hours, but the player has some submissions before that time period too...

Comment: Refer to the picture of my desired output above.

Comment: I have fixed both issues, please see revised answer